# jquery call a button from a different page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, jstree

Im using a jstree custom context menu and Im trying to define the **create** option. I already have a button that performs the intended logic, however it is on a different page. How would I go about using javascript/jQuery to call a button that is on a different page?

Here is my context menu in the javascript file in my page called **middlenav.aspx**. The button I wish to reference is on a page called **navbar.aspx**

**UPDATE**: I was able to get it partially working. I can call the button but it causes my current page to refresh. How can I avoid refreshing the current page **middlenav.aspx**?

```
"contextmenu": {
            "items": function ($node) {
                return {
                    "Create": {
                        "label": "Create",
                        "action": function (obj) {
                            createItem(obj);
                        }
                    },
                    "Rename": {
                        "label": "Edit",
                        "action": function (obj) {
                            this.rename(obj);
                        }
                    },
                    "Delete": {
                        "label": "Delete",
                        "action": function (obj) {
                            this.remove(obj);
                        }
                    }
                };
            }
        },

// Updated
function createItem(obj) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "navbar.aspx",
        success: function (data) {
            $('body').append(data);
            $("#btnNewItem").click();
        }
    });
```

Comment: You cannot call an element that is not in the DOM. You can either refactor the logic to be called and call it from both pages or use Ajax and call the logic method...

Comment: I was able to partially use the ajax approach but it causes my page to refresh. Is it possible to write it in such a way that would avoid this? (see updated code above)

Comment: What @Zaki is saying is to put the logic to your original page in a global javascript file. When you click the button in **either** page, call that global function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the most effective way, but I was able to accomplish it with the following function:

```
function createItem(obj) {
    $.get("navbar.aspx", function (data) {
        $('myHiddenDiv').append(data);
        $("#btnNewItem").click();
        window.stop();
    });
}
```